# Best way to evaluate a survey

Tags: excel, evaluation, survey

I need to evaluate a survey that was made with visitors of an exhibition. Questions were about demographic details of the visitors and how they experienced the exhibition (questions about quality, whether they found it interesting, ...)

Now I don't have to just take each question and make a bar or pie chart from the data, the idea is to filter the data to have results like: How did people under 25 find the exhibition? Were people from abroad as satisfied as people from the region?

My question:
Is there a better solution/tool than storing the data in an Excel sheet and building interactive charts with it?

Comment: Write a summary with charts and quotes from the visitors. Also try to make conclusions from this data and tie it to some key points. Then just have a readable structure in your document, you can have headers for the question and sections under it to display answers for different groups. This summary may also be done in different ways depending on what it will be used for and who will read it etc.

Comment: Without having seen your data, it sure sounds like a pivot table would do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are already aware of them, but one solution would be to use PivotTables or PivotCharts in Excel.  With a PivotTable or PivotChart you can slice and dice the data anyway you need to filter the data and view the results.

There's information available at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-pivottable-and-pivotchart-reports-HP010177384.aspx.

Comment: Thank you! I think PivotTables and PivotCharts will cover my needs. Until now I didn't have a closer look on them because I didn't even know exactly, what you can achieve with it. I now have to say that they are very useful and quite easy to  build charts.